# Display a count of how many times each tag shows up

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, counting

I have an object of users and I am trying to display how many times each tag shows up. *I edited in the ExaltedToast code*

The output I expect is:

quis: 1

irure: 1

consequat: 1

ut: 1

occaecat: 2

..and so forth

The output I get is:

{"quis":1,"irure":1,"consequat":1,"ut":1,"occaecat":2,"esse":1,"qui":1,"in":1,"duis":1,"officia":1,"ipsum":1,"incididunt":2,"ex":1}

**my object of arrays**

```
const users = [
  {
    age: 21,
    eyeColor: "green",
    name: "Gregory Villarreal",
    company: "BLUPLANET",
    tags: ["quis", "irure", "consequat", "ut", "occaecat"],
  },
  {
    age: 39,
    eyeColor: "brown",
    name: "Bowman Jensen",
    company: "HOMETOWN",
    tags: ["esse", "qui", "in", "duis", "occaecat"],
  },
  {
    age: 35,
    eyeColor: "brown",
    name: "Berg Carson",
    company: "WRAPTURE",
    tags: ["officia", "ipsum", "incididunt", "incididunt", "ex"],
  },
];
```

**my code so far**

```
// OLD CODE
// get the tags from the array
const userTags = users.map((user) => (user.tags));

// count the tag occurrences
const tagCount = userTags.reduce((obj, e) => {
    obj[e] = (obj[e] || 0) + 1;
    return obj;
  }, {});

// display the tag occurrences
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tagCount);
document.body.appendChild(div);

//  CURRENT CODE
users.forEach((user) => {
    user.tags.forEach((tag) => {
        tagCount[tag] = (tagCount[tag] | 0) + 1;
    });
});

let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tagCount);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

I have a JSBIN https://jsbin.com/leqeludahi/ and a Code Snippet

```js
const users = [
  {
    age: 21,
    eyeColor: "green",
    name: "Gregory Villarreal",
    company: "BLUPLANET",
    tags: ["quis", "irure", "consequat", "ut", "occaecat"],
  },
  {
    age: 39,
    eyeColor: "brown",
    name: "Bowman Jensen",
    company: "HOMETOWN",
    tags: ["esse", "qui", "in", "duis", "occaecat"],
  },
  {
    age: 35,
    eyeColor: "brown",
    name: "Berg Carson",
    company: "WRAPTURE",
    tags: ["officia", "ipsum", "incididunt", "incididunt", "ex"],
  },
];

const tagCount = {};
users.forEach((user) => {
    user.tags.forEach((tag) => {
        tagCount[tag] = (tagCount[tag] | 0) + 1;
    });
});

let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tagCount);
// div.innerHTML = tagCount.join('\n');
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const tagCount = {};
let div = document.createElement('div');
users.forEach((user) => {
    user.tags.forEach((tag) => {
        tagCount[tag] = (tagCount[tag] | 0) + 1;     
    });

let tagFormat = Object.entries(tagCount).reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
return result + `${key}:${value} <br>`;
}, "");

div.innerHTML = tagFormat;
});

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close, you just need to additionally iterate through the tags in the array, not just add the array directly to the object.

```js
// Get the tags from the array
const userTags = users.map((user) => user.tags);

// Count the tag occurrences
const tagCount = userTags.reduce((obj, e) => {
    for (let tag of e) {
        obj[tag] = (obj[tag] || 0) + 1;
    }
    return obj;
}, {});
```

A considerably cleaner solution is to use a single round of iteration in `forEach`.

```js
let tagCount = {};
users.forEach((user) => {
    user.tags.forEach((tag) => {
        tagCount[tag] = (tagCount[tag] | 0) + 1;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It gets me the proper array it just doesn't display it properly ie it displays as a list.

Comment: Plus I can't access the tagCount array after to make modifications such as tagCount.split(',').join("<br />");

Comment: I updated it with a jsbin https://jsbin.com/leqeludahi/